# How to include a cmake Makefile after a target has been executed?

Tags: cmake

Given the following minimal example.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(include_test)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT OtherCMakeLists.txt
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/create_other_cmakelists")
add_custom_target(do_something DEPENDS OtherCMakeLists.txt)
```

What `do_something` should do here is first create `OtherCMakeLists.txt`. Now, let's assume that `do_something` has to do *something else* afterwards, e.g. compiling some code. I'd like that when the targets from *something else* are executed, the `CMakeLists.txt` will behave as if `OtherCMakeLists.txt` was included with `include`.

Is this possible?

As an example why this could be useful: `OtherCMakeLists.txt` might add some compiler flags that have influence on further compiling.

Comment: To clarify, you first want to build an executable `create_other_cmakelists` then call it and then include the result? Or is `create_other_cmakelists` a script or external executable?

Comment: Reading your question I get the impression you might just be looking for [`try_compile`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/try_compile.html). Could you clarify a little more what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Finn Where is the difference between (1) and (2)? Aside from this: create_other_cmakelists is indeed a script which can be assumed to already exist.

Comment: @ComicSansMS `try_compile` looks much more weak than include. In my case (as the example in the question states), I'd like to change compiler flags in the OtherCMakeLists.txt. I'm almost sure that `try_compile` will not do that?

Comment: The answers of @Peter and @Antwane already covered what I was going for. If you can run `create_other_cmakelists` without building it with your complete project, you can run it with `execute_process`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, it is not possible to generate CMakeLists.txt file with a custom target/command and use `include` CMake command with generated CMakeLists.txt

The problem is that the `include` command is called at so-called "Configuration time" (when `cmake` executable tries to parse all CMakeLists.txt), but the generation of file (CMakeLists.txt) is performed at "Build time" (when `make` command is invoked on generated build system)

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this if no one will post a solution which contradicts your answer.

Answer (score 1):

add_custom_command has 2 different signatures:

- `add_custom_command(OUTPUT ...)` will be executed **at build time**, too late to apply rules from a generated CMakeLists.txt generated.
- `add_custom_command(TARGET ...)` to attach a specific command to a target. This command can be run on PRE_BUILD, PRE_LINK or POST_BUILD. Probably not what you want to achieve...

If you are trying to add some dynamic to your compile process, adding custom commands or target may not be your best option.

You should try to read doc for some other CMake commands that can be helpful in your case:

- [configure_file()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/configure_file.html) that can process a file (OtherCMakeLists.txt.in) into another file (OtherCMakeLists.txt) replacing variables by their values. This is achieved **at configuration time**
- [execute_process()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/execute_process.html) to run a command a **configuration time** (thx to @ComicSansMS)
- [set_target_properties()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/set_target_properties.html) to set some compiler or link flags to a specific target depending on some conditions
- The list of [properties you can set on targets](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-targets)

Comment: As an addition to your list: [`execute_process`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/execute_process.html) is quite useful for stuff that would fit into custom commands, but needs to be executed at CMake configure time instead of build time.

Comment: Thanks. However, your answer does not seem to give any hint about to solve the include dynamically issue, right?

Comment: As @Peter explained, include() command is executed at configuration time. But some of the commands mentionned in this answer are also executed while configuring project. So you probably have solutions to do what you want based on the commands mentionned above